# Dropdown relative positioning issue

Tags: javascript, css, drop-down-menu, css-position

I have 3 buttons that will each trigger their own dropdown content div. I need the dropdowns to span the full width of the page. I know I can change the dropdowns to have a position of :absolute to achieve full width but this causes a problem by positioning itself above the footer rather than pushing it down.

It's probably something basic that I'm missing in my css but I've spent hours trying to debug this and I've had no luck.

I've a codepen set up in the comments

Any help at all would be much appreciated.

Comment: http://codepen.io/caseybr/pen/MygBZP

Comment: Is there any reason the dropdowns need to be inside of the `<li>`s? That's the reason they're not spanning the full page width.

Comment: If your dropdowns dont need to be the child of anything, put them into the body or something.

Comment: When I remove it from the li the dropdown won't fire for some reason..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to make it work without using `position: absolute` you are gonna have to change the html markup a little bit.

You will have to move all of the `.toggleContent` `div`s out of the `li`s, because when you try to make them full width they are limited by the `li`'s width (you are using 100% in your example). You can move the `div`s anywhere you like.

Now you will also have to change the jQuery events because they are dependent on the markup to work. You only have to change the first few lines for it to work:

```
$("button.expand").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $(this).toggleClass("active");
     $('.toggleContent').slideToggle('slow');
     return false;
});
```

Here is how it looks when it's all done: [**example**](http://codepen.io/Ayeetu/pen/pyzObG?editors=1010).

Comment: Thanks so much. I've spent the past few hours pulling my hair out over this!!

Comment: No problem if it helped be sure to mark the answer as the right one :)